# Difference between 7" and 5" LCDs with arduino

Tags: arduino

First this isn't a programing question.
I used to have a 5" LCD with model name "ITDB50" with 800×480 resolution but it's broken now and I can't find a new one in the market, but there is another LCD with 7" display and model name "TFT01-7", it has the same functionality and the same resolution as my 5" LCD.
My question is:
If I bought this 7" LCD and uploaded my code to it will it work the same as my 5" LCD (as both of them have the same resolution), or do I have to change my code?

Link to 5" LCD:
https://www.itead.cc/itdb02-5-0.html

Link to 7" LCD:
http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=7.0%22_Width_800*480_TFT_LCD_Module

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate venue for this kind of question (non-programming). That said, you 'll probably need to find and compare (or at least post links to them in the aforementioned forum) the data sheets for both LCD displays. If they use the same controller, chances are they will be compatible but to be sure you 'll have to check the details.

Comment: I did check the data sheets and made the researches, but I needed to be sure so I asked my question, and I will update it with the links to both of the LCDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may work because both screens have same controller SSD1963. I also found that they have almost same 40 pin connector pinout. The only difference is in sd card SO and SI pins. [5 inch wiki](http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/ITDB02-5.0) and [7 inch wiki](http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=7.0%22_Width_800*480_TFT_LCD_Module)